# Chatterbot how to get multiple responses

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, corpus, chatterbot

the python chatterbot library given the datasets below convo.txt

output.txt

```js
hey
hey 1
hey
hey 2
hey
hey 3
```

or when trained on this dataset, in corpus with the dataset below (yml)

```js
- - hey
  - hey 1
- - hey
  - hey 2
- - hey
  - hey 3
```

when get_response('hey') is called, hey 1 and hey 2 are the only ones given, why is that? and how can i have multiple responses available when users type 'hey', i want it to randomly generate between hey 1 hey 2 and hey 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Corpus trainer, it works much better than from a text file, and delete your database every time to make sure you are getting the proper output.

```js
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.custom')
```